# Generic ArrayList of Integers Storing Strings Instead?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, arraylist, casting

So here's what I am trying to do. I have a generic class called

```
public class SortsTextFile<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

That stores an ArrayList called

```
private ArrayList<T> listFromFile = null;
```

So, when it's time to grab the elements from the given text file, this code runs

```
try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                 new FileReader(listInfo)))
    {
        listFromFile = new ArrayList<>();

        String line = in.readLine();
        while (line != null)
        {
            String[] columns = line.split(FIELD_SEP);

            for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++)
            {
                listFromFile.add((T) columns[i]);
            }
            line = in.readLine();
        }
    }
```

This code runs fine, but as the title implies, instead of properly being casted into type T which would be type Integer in this case, they stay as type Strings from the text file and get added into the array as strings instead of integers.

How do I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Casting and converting are not the same thing. If you want it to convert a value from one type to another, you have to specify how.

Comment: Your IDE should have given you some yellow squigglies on the `(T)` cast, with a tooltip saying something about an unchecked cast. Pay attention to the yellow squigglies. They're important.

Comment: I'm trying sort various data structures, right now I'm trying to make it work with Strings and Integers. The situation is I'm giving it a text file full of numbers which I can make into an array of strings with the help of the split() method which then I need to convert to the given type of either String or Integer, this class has generics so it can do both seamessly, this is the only problem area I have right now.

Comment: I use Netbeans and I see no such unchecked cast.

Comment: If casting and converting are different, then how do I convert the value into an integer if T happens to be of type Integer?

Comment: Maybe Netbeans uses something other than squiggly lines, or maybe you used `SuppressWarnings` (*don't use `SuppressWarnings`*). Whatever the presentation, you should have received a warning.

Comment: You really don't believe me, huh. Well, see for yourself: https://imgur.com/a/Tjyqhqa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`T` is only required to be `Comparable`, and `String` is `Comparable`. Also, you are adding `columns` which is a `String[]`. If you want `Integer`, you must *convert* it yourself. Assuming the values are actually integral, simplest fix would be to change

```
listFromFile.add((T) columns[i]);
```

to

```
listFromFile.add((T) Integer.valueOf(columns[i]));
```

And I'm not certain the cast is necessary. Also, I think

```
public class SortsTextFile<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

should be

```
public class SortsTextFile<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work for me, since the ArrayList is generic so I can do sorts on both lists full of Strings and lists full of Integers. That would work fantastically if I could check what the generic type is and then apply that, would that be possible?

Comment: Now, in the case if the cast fails, how do I make sure it leaves it as a String and not crash the program?

Comment: @Alex <T> is *either* String or Integer. One *instance* can't have two types. Either make two lists, or simply use Object and customise a comparator for comparison. Also, stackoverflow is not chatroom; if you want to learn in a chat style checkout the [Java chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139/java).

Comment: I know it can't be two different types, I'm saying whenever I run in instance where T IS a String how do I make sure that Integer.valueOf() conversion doesn't occur? Is there a way to check for T so I can easily apply an if or else check?

Comment: try {} catch {}

Comment: Save a reference to `Class<T>` (typically by passing it to the constructor at runtime), then you can use `if (Integer.class.isAssignableFrom(cls))` and `if (String.class.isAssignableFrom(cls))` - note that here we are *parsing* int values, so the type you get from the file is always a `String`!

Comment: A try-catch block makes a lot of sense. Also the Class<T> reference sounds super creative, I'll try that if the try-catch doesn't work out.